# 'puppet resource service' does not work

Tags: puppet

I have the following error:

```
piousbox@piousbox-laptop:~$ puppet resource service
Error: Could not run: Execution of '/sbin/status bridge-network-interface' returned 1: 
status: Unknown parameter: INTERFACE
```

running `/sbin/status bridge-network-interface` errors out, but running `/sbin/status bridge-network-interface INTERFACE=eth0` does not. Where in puppet do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Puppet has issues dealing with upstart services like that (Example [#21478](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/21478)).  Below is one example issue including how they worked around it by modifying `puppet/providers/package/upstart.rb`.

For example, if you added the below at line 46 in that file, it would "fix" your issue.

```
elsif matcher = line.match(/^(bridge-network-interface)\s\(([^\)]+)\)/)
        "#{matcher[1]} INTERFACE=#{matcher[2]}"
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. That modification is in the code I run (puppet 3.2.2) and it gives the same error..